# Advantages to knowing $p$ and $q$ in Blum Blum Shub?

Tags: blum-blum-shub

Do you gain any advantage by knowing the factorization of $M$ (over just knowing $M$ itself) in the [Blum Blum Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) generator?

The only advantage I see is being able to calculate the $i$-th number directly, as opposed to iterating to it.  This doesn't seem like a very large gain to me.

Comment: Using CRT to speed up the computation?

Comment: @mikeazo: actually, I think you have something, even if we're just computing the next output.  If $p$ and $q$ are both $n$ bits, then doing BBS naively uses a $2n$-bit modular multiplication; with CRT, we end up with 3 $n$-bit modular multiplications (plus some additions/subtractions); if we assume a standard $O(N^2)$ multiplication algorithm, this is a win.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: knowing $p$ and $q$ allows building a more efficient generator, including one with [random access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access). Further, for an adversary, at least if $p-1$ and $q-1$ can be factored, that allows finding a period, and at least if the generator allows random access past that, building a distinguisher.

---

With secret seed $x_0$, the [Blum Blum Shub generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) computes output $f(x_i)$ for $i\ge1$, where $x_i$ is defined by the recurrence $x_{i+1}={x_i}^2\bmod M$, and $f()$ is some function [such as extraction of the low bit, or eXclusive-OR or all bits], and $M=p\cdot q$ with $p$ and $q$ large distinct primes with $p\equiv q\equiv 3\pmod4$.

That implies $x_i={x_0}^{(2^i)}\bmod M$, but direct evaluation of that expression has cost $\mathcal O(i)$, and is equivalent to directly applying the recurrence.

With knowledge of the factorization $M=p\cdot q$, we can compute the output for large $i$ directly and efficiently [in time $\mathcal O(\log(i))$], by computing ${x_0}^{2^i\bmod(p-1)}\bmod p$ and ${x_0}^{2^i\bmod(q-1)}\bmod q$, then using the [Chineese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to combine them into $x_i$. The CRT may also slightly speed up a generator proceeding using the recurrence, as [pointed my mikeaso](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16271/advantages-to-knowing-p-and-q-in-blum-blum-shub#comment35671_16271) and [made quantitative by poncho](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16271/advantages-to-knowing-p-and-q-in-blum-blum-shub#comment35674_16271) in comments (computation time can be reduced by up to $1/4$ with textbook multiplication algorithms).

An adversary (with no access to the full internal state of the generator) knowing the factorization of $M=p\cdot q$, and also able to factor $p-1$ and $q-1$, can compute $u=\lambda(p-1)$ and $v=\lambda(q-1)$ where $\lambda()$ is [Carmichael's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) [or $u=\varphi(p-1)$ and $v=\varphi(q-1)$ where $\varphi()$ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totient_function)], then $\operatorname{lcm}(u,v)$ which is a multiple of the period of the BBS generator, because for all $x$, $x^{(2^u)}\equiv x\pmod p$ and $x^{(2^v)}\equiv x\pmod q$. From that it is trivial to build a distinguisher between

- a BBS black box accepting $i>0$ and returning the output of index $i$ in the BBS sequence for some fixed unknown random seed $x$;
- a random oracle black box accepting $i>0$ and returning random output if that $i$ was not previously submitted, else returning its previous output for this $i$.

The distinguisher works by submitting $i=1$ and $i=\operatorname{lcm}(u,v)+1$, bets on BBS if the answers are equal, and on random oracle otherwise.

When

- the BBS black box only outputs sequentially,
- or proceeds sequentially by squaring modulo $M$,
- or otherwise bounds $i$ to remain small,
- or was built without knowledge of the factorization of $M$,
- or $p-1$ or $q-1$ are hard to factor,

then I fail to exhibit a distinguisher (but would no be all that surprised if one could be devised).

Answer (score 1):

Finding square roots modulo $M$ is difficult when $M$ is not prime. However, knowing the factors of $M$ lets one take the short cut of finding the roots modulo $p$ and $q$ (fast because they are prime), then using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to combine those to find roots modulo $M$.

I'm not sure how/whether that breaks Blum Blum Shub, though.

Comment: I believe the question was "what advantage would the legitimate generator have in retaining $p$ and $q$", not "if an adversary learned $p$ and $q$, how can they attack it"

Comment: Ok, my answer was rather off topic in that case.